# How do I hide TracerPID from a process?

Tags: proc, strace, sqlserver, ltrace, reverse-engineering

I'm conjecturing [SQL Server on Linux is checking `/proc/self/status` for `TracerPID` and then dying if it's not `0`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/194205/2639). I want to test that. Playing around, here is the strace,

```
... lots of stuff
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/status", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(5, "Name:\tsqlservr\nUmask:\t0022\nState"..., 1024) = 1024
close(5)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
getpid()                                = 28046
gettid()                                = 28046
tgkill(28046, 28046, SIGABRT)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=28046, si_uid=999} ---
gettid()                                = 28046
write(2, "Dump collecting thread [28046] h"..., 59Dump collecting thread [28046] hit exception [6]. Exiting.
) = 59
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
```

The `ltrace` is even more damning, thankfully they're using `strstr` which makes it seem *really* likely my theory is correct.

```
strstr("PPid:\t28515\n", "TracerPid:")                                                                  = nil
__getdelim(0x7ffc0b7d2330, 0x7ffc0b7d2328, 10, 0x7f12f5811980)                                          = 17
strstr("TracerPid:\t28515\n", "TracerPid:")                                                             = "TracerPid:\t28515\n"
strtol(0x7f12f581840b, 0x7ffc0b7d2320, 10, 0)                                                           = 0x6f63
free(0x7f12f5818400)                                                                                    = <void>
fclose(0x7f12f5811980)                                                                                  = 0
abort( <no return ...>
--- SIGABRT (Aborted) ---
syscall(186, 6, 0, 0)                                                                                   = 0x6f64
fprintf(0x7f12f6ec4640, "Dump collecting thread [%d] hit "..., 28516, 6Dump collecting thread [28516] hit exception [6]. Exiting.
)                                = 59
fflush(0x7f12f6ec4640)                                                                                  = 0
exit(-1 <unfinished ...>
```

The last line on the file they check (with `strstr`) before they `abort()` is the line with `TracerPid:`, however with my `/proc/self/status` there are many lines after it.

In order of preference, I'd like `/proc/self/status` to report

```
...stuff...
TracerPid:  0
...stuff...
```

for this process. If that can't be achieved, I'd like it to report `0` for all processes.

Is it possible to create a wrapper that changes the value of `TracerPID` for `/proc/self/status` and then `exec` the argument given to it resulting in it not having access to `TracerPID`?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found to do this by [patching the kernel](https://gist.github.com/doughgle/e3a8c350dbf2370e69212f8b91fa4c88#file-gistfile1-txt-L17). Though I think it may also be possible to hack this of thing with `LD_PRELOAD`, I'll check into later.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the kernel patch may be a more interesting solution if you want to debug other programs protected in the same way. For instance, `gdb` uses the same trick to detect if is being debugged.

However, based on your question, I investigated how to modify the mssql server behaviour when `TracerPID` is showing a PID different than 0 ; and I believe I found out a cleaner solution.

I used Hopper for disassembling/decompiling the MS SQL server binary file `sqlservr` and found the offending subroutine that checks TracerPID for preventing debugging.

In Hopper output, decompiled, the offending function is:

```
int sub_2d6d0() {
    r14 = fopen(0xa9b4e, 0xb6444);
    rbx = 0x0;
    if (r14 == 0x0) goto loc_2d791;

loc_2d702:
    var_30 = 0x0;
    var_38 = 0x0;
    r15 = &var_30;
    r12 = &var_38;
    goto loc_2d730;

loc_2d730:
    rbx = 0x0;
    if (__getdelim(r15, r12, 0xa, r14) < 0x0) goto loc_2d77b;

loc_2d74a:
    rax = strstr(var_30, "TracerPid:");
    if (rax == 0x0) goto loc_2d730;

loc_2d75b:
    var_40 = 0x0;
    rbx = strtol(rax + 0xb, &var_40, 0xa);
    goto loc_2d77b;

loc_2d77b:
    rdi = var_30;
    if (rdi != 0x0) {
            free(rdi);
    }
    fclose(r14);
    goto loc_2d791;

loc_2d791:
    rax = rbx;
    return rax;
}
```

In (heavily edited) human interpretation, the C pseudo-code of the function is:

```
int  IsMonitorProcess() {                          ; sub_2d6d0
    FILE * f = fopen("/proc/self/", "r" );
    int pid = 0;                                   ; rbx
    char *s = NULL;

    if (f != NULL ) 
    {             
        while (__getdelim(s, 0, 0xa, f) >= 0x0) 
        {
            char *temp;

            temp = strstr(s, "TracerPid:");
            pid = 0;
            if (temp != NULL)
                pid = strtol(temp + 0xb, NULL, 10);
        }

        if (s != NULL) {
               free(s);
        }

        fclose(f);
    }

    return pid;
}
```

As it can be seen, if `strstr` finds the string "TracerPid:", temp/*rax* will be different than 0(NULL).

The `strtol` will then be invoked to convert the remaining of the string to a (long) integer. *rbx* with then been loaded with the value returned by `strtol` (which actually in the disassembly listing, is in *rax*).

So there are two more solutions for disabling the tracing detection, besides patching the kernel as you mention:

- The cleaner solution: You write a library to be loaded with LD_PRELOAD when invoking `sqlservr`.

What I advise as the simplest solution is intercepting `strstr` and `strtol`, in which you write code in `strstr` that when it founds "TracerPid:", it will activate a flag that makes the next `strtol` invocation return 0.

(I already double checked the binary, and indeed, `strstr` and `strtol` are dynamically loaded)

Another option is intercepting `fopen`, however the code might be a bit more complicated.

- the `sqlservr` binary is patched, you replace `rax = rbx` for `rax = 0`, as *rbx* holds the `strtol`/string to long integer conversion of the value after "TracerPid:".

The disadvantage of this solution is that each new version will have to be patched again.

Actually in the assembly itself, the *rbx* register loading comes right after calling `strtol`. The binary can be patched from `mov        rbx, rax` to `xor rbx,rbx` or `mov rbx,0`, which one is shorter.

```
000000000002d75b         mov        qword [rbp+var_40], 0x0
000000000002d763         add        rax, 0xb
000000000002d767         lea        rsi, qword [rbp+var_40]                     ; argument "__endptr" for method j_strtol
000000000002d76b         mov        edx, 0xa                                    ; argument "__base" for method j_strtol
000000000002d770         mov        rdi, rax                                    ; argument "__nptr" for method j_strtol
000000000002d773         call       j_strtol                                    ; strtol
000000000002d778         mov        rbx, rax   <----------- xor rbx,rbx

                     loc_2d77b:
000000000002d77b         mov        rdi, qword [rbp+var_30]                     ; CODE XREF=sub_2d6d0+120
000000000002d77f         test       rdi, rdi
000000000002d782         je         loc_2d789

000000000002d784         call       j_free                                      ; free

                     loc_2d789:
000000000002d789         mov        rdi, r14                                    ; argument "__stream" for method j_fclose, CODE XREF=sub_2d6d0+178
000000000002d78c         call       j_fclose
```

Obviously I do advise using the `LD_PRELOAD` solution instead of either trying to patch the kernel or the binary itself.

It is a much cleaner solution, and it is not dependent on having to be done again each time you got a MSSQL or a kernel upgrade.

Note: I downloaded `mssql-server_14.0.3008.27-1_amd64.deb` and decompressed it on a Mac.

As for the source code for the LD_PRELOAD library, the general idea is roughly:

```
int flag = 0;

char * strstr (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    if(!strcmp(s2, "TracerPid:"))
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    .... rest of usual code
}

long strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, register int base)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        flag = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    .... rest of usual code
}
```

Commenting about `fopen` pointing only to `"/proc/self/"`: It is not a mistake.

Yes, I find it odd the `fopen` being done to `"/proc/self/"` only. Most probably, the couple of integer variables after it are just there for filling a space, that will be used completing the rest of the string at runtime, and it is a cheap trick for deceiving anyone who is trying to look at the binary.