# Can getauxval be used to determine whether or not you're being traced?

Tags: strace, sqlserver, tracing, ltrace

Coming off of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413697/3285), I patched my kernel in a quest to get SQL Server 2017 on Linux to start up. Now I'm getting further but I'm being shut down,

```
strstr("TracerPid:\t0\n", "TracerPid:")                                                                 = "TracerPid:\t0\n"
strtol(0x7fe0cf01840b, 0x7ffd380d5eb0, 10, 0)                                                           = 0
free(0x7fe0cf018400)                                                                                    = <void>
fclose(0x7fe0cf011980)                                                                                  = 0
getpid()                                                                                                = 3474
getpid()                                                                                                = 3474
getauxval(31, 9, 5, 0x7fe0d034ea67)                                                                     = 0x7ffd380dcfe0
strncpy(0x7ffd380d5f00, "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr", 4095)                                                = 0x7ffd380d5f00
realpath(0x7ffd380d5f00, 0x7ffd380d6f00, 0, 0x7fe0d0323720)                                             = 0x7ffd380d6f00
getpid()                                                                                                = 3474
abort( <no return ...>
--- SIGABRT (Aborted) ---
```

I believe after having check `proc`, SQL Server does some other voodoo to do the same thing as a fall back, just to be "extra-safe" that no one is trying to make their software work.

Now, I'm wondering if `getauxval(3)` can be used to also determine if a process is being traced? It seems that the [`CAPABILITIES`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) indicate this is possible in `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` and `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the first argument to `GETAUXVAL()` says something,

```
getauxval(31, 9, 5, 0x7fe0d034ea67)
```

Opening up [`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/auxv.h`](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/i386/libc6-dev/2.19-0ubuntu6/file/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/auxv.h), I can see that

```
#define AT_EXECFN       31              /* Filename of executable.  */
```

So they're trying to get the filename of the executable -- actually the pathname per the docs and the example below. In this case that's the pathname of the tracer and not the target. They're then calling `realpath` to make sure the paths are the same. You can see what `getauxval()`,

```
$ LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 strace sleep 1
AT_SYSINFO_EHDR: 0x7ffd6d96f000
AT_HWCAP:        bfebfbff
AT_PAGESZ:       4096
AT_CLKTCK:       100
AT_PHDR:         0x5640b6cad040
AT_PHENT:        56
AT_PHNUM:        9
AT_BASE:         0x7fc9ce4fc000
AT_FLAGS:        0x0
AT_ENTRY:        0x5640b6d09440
AT_UID:          1000
AT_EUID:         1000
AT_GID:          1000
AT_EGID:         1000
AT_SECURE:       0
AT_RANDOM:       0x7ffd6d909669
AT_HWCAP2:       0x0
AT_EXECFN:       /usr/bin/strace
AT_PLATFORM:     x86_64
```